# How to fix errors when update project from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14

Tags: xcode

I was trying to update my project from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14.

But I got a lot of errors. They are similar but I don't know how to fix them. Take a look in the image below:

[image: Text]

It's the same error that appears in a lot of files.

I try to click on "Type declared here".

[image: Text]

But it didn't appear the error inside the Swift file.

When I click on "self declared here", I see this

[image: Text]

It shows no error on the file.

When I was clicking on the errors, they vanish sometimes, but for some unknown reason, they reappear after some time.

Anyone got any idea of how to fix this?

EDIT 1:

The problem is related to the "OcrProcessingViewController" class.

I comment this class and the code starts to work again. But I still din't find what was causing the problem.

If I restore the code, I can see only one error now.

[image: Text]

This is the full code on my "OcrProcessingViewController" class file

https://swiftfiddle.com/kfmxwr6snrbknne3msmapvkx5m

I suspect it is related to the "protocol CodigoOcrDataDelegate: AnyObject", but I don't know how yet how this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what was causing the problem.

It was the property

```
lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNRecognizeTextRequest = {
    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: handleDetectedText)
    request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    request.recognitionLanguages = ["en_GB"]
    return request
}()
```

I just need to move it to start of the class(removing it from inside the function) and everything works perfectly now on Xcode 14